# audio player html5 problem with my javascript, just works on localhost

Tags: javascript, loops, html5-audio

I'm trying to create an audio player with several track list for render this i'm using that html code

```
<p>Clearwater... <a href="#" class="openaudio" data-value="/assets/audio/1.mp3" data-text="Swing">[plays audio]</a></p>
<p>Blues... <a href="#" class="openaudio" data-value="/assets/audio/2.mp3" data-text="Swing">[plays audio]</a></p>
```

and more links...

To change the track, i'm using this javascript code :

```
// Loop through each link and add the event listener
audioLinks.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elm = e.target;
    var audio = document.querySelector("#audio");
    var source = document.getElementById('audioSource');
    source.src = elm.getAttribute('data-value');
    audio.load(); 
    audio.play();
    audiomodal.style.display = "block";
    console.log(source.src)
  });
});
```

there is also an audio spectrum after this code but it seems that the problem is not in this part because it doesn't work when commented.

So what the problem :
In localhost everything ok (sometimes needed to refresh the page) the track is loaded and start well, the audio files src change when the links are clicked.

But when i'm trying to put the code online the problems begin :
the audio files are well loaded but do not start even if i have clicked on the native audio player of the navigator. I'm sure the files are correctly loaded when inspecting the code and click the option download of the player (files founded).

the HTML part for the player :

```
<div id="audiomodal" class="audiomodal">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<h2>En écoute : </h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="song">
<canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height="100px"></canvas>
<audio id="audio" controls="controls" preload="auto"><source id="audioSource" src="" type="audio/mpeg">Votre navigateur ne supporte pas cette fonctionnalité</audio>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I really don't understand my mistake

Thanks for your help

Comment: My blind guess is that you're calling play() before the file is actually loaded, so you'll have to set up an event listener for the canplaythrough event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event